# How to preety print a particular python dict list as java script object from dictionary using React JS

Tags: python-3.x, reactjs

```
"raw_data":{
"data":{
"dailies":[\"{'summaryId': 'x209bf59-59b8ad40-a320-6', 'activityType': 'WALKING'}"\],
"activities":[\"{'durationInSeconds': 68, 'startTimeInSeconds': 1505244147}"\],
"walk":[\"{'weightInGrams': 81237, 'measurementTimeInSeconds': 1505275200}"\]

}
}
```

i have to print activites string as a javascript object using ReactJS

Comment: Where is the relevant javascript code? What have you tried so far?

Comment: am new to reactJS and python ,so am unable to understand the requirment ,i didnt get any hint from browse please can u let me know how  to proceed

Answer (score 0):

Read about [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) functions of javascript.